# Setting up ssl certificate on apache server with virtual hosts

Tags: ssl, apache2, debian, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to set up a digicert ssl wildcard certificate for my apache server. I'm a bit confuse about something. I have the following config so far:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName x.y.com
  ServerAlias x.y.com
  DocumentRoot /webapps/x/public
  <Directory /webapps/x/public>
    Options -MultiViews
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/y.com_error.log
  LogLevel warn
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/y.com_access.log combined
  ServerSignature On
</VirtualHost>

NameVirtualHost *:443
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName x.y.com
  ServerAlias x.y.com
  DocumentRoot /webapps/x/public
  <Directory /webapps/x/public>
    Options -MultiViews
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/y.com_error.log
  LogLevel warn
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/y.com_access.log combined
  ServerSignature On

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/certificates/www_y_com.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/certificates/www_y_com.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/certificates/DigiCertCA.crt
  RailsEnv myenv
</VirtualHost>
```

But I get:

> NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts (98)Address already in use:
>   make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:443 no listening sockets
>   available, shutting down

How should I configure this in order to make it work?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Perhaps you should ask this question on [sf].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a glance your virtual host XML looks correct.
I usually write the NameVirtualHost directive in the ports.conf file and then each virtual host must have its own file. On my system its located at /etc/apache2/sites-available/your-domain-name

One more thing. Make sure port 443 is open in your router. I forget this all the time and spend hours trying to figure something out when its as simple as port forwarding 443 to your server ip from within your router config.

Also don't forget to enable the site.

```
# enable site
sudo a2ensite

# disable site
sudo a2dissite
```